# SQL Server read all tables in a database but also access metadata (db_datareader fixed db role insufficient)

Tags: sql-server

We use SQL Server 2017 (v14.0.3460.9 - KB5021126).

We would like to provide read-only access to all tables in selected databases on a SQL Server instance to an account (looks like an MSA but not sure) that would be used to export table content.

We also need the account to be able to query metadata in order to retrieve the list of tables in each database (so able to read `sys` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schemas).

At the moment I have simply assigned `db_owner` role to the account for each of the databases required, I'd like to have used `db_datareader` but it can only read user tables.

I don't like assigning the `db_owner` role, what is a better way to do this please?

Comment: For most `sys` views which refer to objects in the database: *"The visibility of the metadata in catalog views is limited to securables that a user either owns or on which the user has been granted some permission."* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/metadata-visibility-configuration?view=sql-server-ver16 So in theory `db_datareader` should be enough. What query is it running that isn't working with that role?

Comment: I don't know, I'm just trying to set up minimal security. The queries haven't been written yet. The first query will read from sys.tables or INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables to gain the list of tables, then a list of export/extract queries will be created from this information I'm working from this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16
*Members of the db_datareader fixed database role can read all data from all user tables and views. User objects can exist in any schema except sys and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.*

Comment: I read this to mean that the db_datareader fixed database role can read user tables and views except when they are in the sys and INFORMATION_SCHEMA schemas???
Doesn't matter, I'll assign db_datareader role instead and if that fails will revert back to db_owner.

Comment: No they can read data in those system views which refer to tables that they have some permissions on.

Comment: Many thanks, sorted now

Answer (score 0):

I set the account up with `db_datareader` and `db_denydatawriter` and then used this to test it:

```
EXECUTE AS USER='domain\account'; SELECT * FROM sys.tables;
```